# How to retrieve useful statistics about a Solana program

Tags: api

Do you know how could I get Solana Program Stats? I've seen similar thing on Solscan, but they seem to not have it in their documentation as API available to Devs. Thank you for help.

Comment: What kind of stats are you looking for?

Comment: Interactions amount since program was deployed.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Dune Analytics](https://dune.com/docs/api/) or [Flipside](https://docs.flipsidecrypto.com/api-sdk-developers/getting-started)

These services provide both user-facing dashboards, and APIs that support SQL queries for different Solana programs. You may have to mess around on the playground, and cross-reference some explorers to get a feel for it.

This was a sample query I did to get all of the instructions called on a program I previously wrote:

```
select instruction, block_timestamp
from solana.core.fact_events
where program_id = '7XajpmvbZwBkGg9Rrz9fb8iHdy1uWhiSVwVsdrGUSk7P'
group by block_timestamp, program_id, instruction
order by block_timestamp desc
```

With Flipside, you can test these queries in the playground, and submit them to the API or SDK for execution and use on your own dashboard.